# HTTPS assets loading over HTTP, even though src is specified as 'https'

Tags: https, mixed-content

So, a strange phenomenom: I have an image which is loading over 'http,' even though 'https' is specified in the src attribute.

Page here: https://universitybusiness.co.uk/
When you hover over the 'stories' menu item the page becomes unsecure, as the magazine image is loaded.

Image here: https://wildfirecomms-images.co.uk/covers/ub_cover_march_v2.jpg

The image is from another domain, however this has a SSL certficate on it. Another strange thing is, the footer staff icons are loaded over https from the same domain.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

This image is requested from https://**www**.wildfirecomms-images.co.uk unlike the other links which omit the www.

`https://www.` performs a 301-redirect to `http://wildfirecomms...` which is the issue, so simply remove the www. from the url.

Comment: That is odd, I've just changed the link and confirm this fixes the current issue. Thank you Alex I didn't spot that difference